# Compiling a python script to run on mac and windows

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, compilation, cross-compiling

I have recently compiled a script (`Python`) to run on windows computers (`.exe`). I was wondering if it was possible to compile a script to work on mac as currently I cant compile for them, and a lot of my friends who program too use macs. I used `Cx-freeze` to compile my python script into an `exe`, but I don't believe it is possible to use this to compile for windows.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not provide the actual Python script itself?

Comment: I mean thats possible but its not required because I person have this problem with every script i compile you cant run .exes on mac and so i was wondering if its possible to create something that can be used on a mac

Comment: But you can run every .py script on MacOS: Python is installed by default there.

Comment: so there's no reason to create executives like on windows? my script uses google apis and other imported library's that have to be added to the current python install

Comment: There's no reason to create a stand-alone executable on Windows either, if people have Python installed. You do run into trouble if you have additional, non-standard, packages that need to be installed. I don't know a way to create a stand-alone executable on a Mac from a Python script, so you may opt to have someone install those packages. Using `pip` and the `--user` option makes that relatively painless, though not as easy as just running a single executable.

Comment: there is though... alot of my friends who arent programmers dont have python installed nor do they have the libraries for google api and stuff... not even my friend who write in python have some of the google api libraries

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use `py2app` module with this command

`pip install py2app`